# Running a method for each field existing in the mysql table

Tags: php

Hello i have a small table in mysql which contains few fields with a description, name, price, id.
Foreach of the items inserted in this table i need to run a certain method in php to make some math based on the price field. How could i do this any ideas(in the future they will be more than two or three so it should be something a little bit dynamic if posible ) .

Update: this is the table.

```
-- Dumping structure for table print_finishes
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `print_finishes`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `print_finishes` (
  `FinishesId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FinishesName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `FinishesPrice` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FinishesId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Update: Ok for those who didn't quite understand my question:
IN PHP:

1. I make a select based on the id's that are comming from a form.
2. Irun a foreach to loop data that is returned from mysql.
3. Now i need away to call up a method that is unique for each of the fields that i
   return. ( this is the part that i don't know how to do it.

Example data returned

1. CutContour - 2euros
2. Laminate - 5euros

in that foreach i need to check somehow if i have a cutcontour option or something like that and run a method called CalculatePriceBasedOnCutContour ( which in my case the formula would be square meters multiplied by 2 euros now when it finds laminate option i need to run another method for example CalculatePricebasedOnLaminate (in this case i could use the same method that i called for cutcontour because the formula would be the same only the price changes.

```
/**
 * Calculate Finishes for cut countour
 * @param int $cutContourPrice [description]
 * @param int $squareMeters    [description]
 */
public function CalculateWithFinishes($cutContourPrice, $squareMeters ) {
    $this->_cutContourPrice = $cutContourPrice * $squareMeters;
}
```

Third Update:
A simple way of doing would be like this:

```
if($printFinishes['name'] = 'CutContour) {
    $this->CalculateWithFinishes($arg1, $arg2);
}
```

and this should be made dynamic because i can't know how they will be named in database

**It was too long to post it as a comment.**

---

A unique method based on the type selected. but i can have even three types selected from finishes tables. i can have laminate, cut contour, bonding on cmyk forex ( each of these finishes has a different price and some of them are calculated based on square meters ) to give a better understanding on what i'm doing it is about storing orders from a print shop in database and make price calculations and reports at the end of the month how much material was printed, how much was lost, how much material was lost during printing process and when it comes to order we have a big list of finishes based for each product. if you print on vinyl you could have even 5 types of finishes applied to it some of them calculated in square meters some of them not and i need to know what formulas should i apply and when based on what i select from a form.
So when i get the data from the form and get the required prices from the database i need a way to find out what finishes i applied to know what function i call to calculate the price.
This is how i calculate on daily bases:
Width * Height * finishes price * print square meter price * euro price * vat tax.
1.37 * 2 * 3 = 8.22 euros the cost of cut contour on the print
1.37 * 2 * 10 = 27.4 euros the cost of the printing process
35.62 * 4.5 * 1.24 = the total cost of the printing with finishes converted to my curency and added the vat tax 
Translation width of the material multiplied by height ( everything is in meters ), that returns me the square meter then i apply a finishes price of 3 ( cut contour on the print ), then i apply the print price ( 10 euros / square meter ) then i convert the euro in my curency then i apply a vat tax on the final price.

Comment: What method? Please explain this better.

Comment: i've posted one of the methods that i have in my class. most of them are based on the same formulare and i will probabe make a general method that i will call it. but for others it doesn't work the same way i need to do other calculations that require more complex formulas to use.
As i've said in my edit with those to examples for cut contour i will use a method for laminate i will use another method

Comment: If I understood correct: You want list all your products like "Laminate - 5euros" and run a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little example:

```
<?php
mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);
//Connecting to the server
mysqli_select_db($yourdb);
//Select DB
$query=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM print_finishes");
//Query
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
//While PHP can get a new row from the output
echo $row['FinishesId'];
echo '<BR>';
echo $row['FinishesName'];
echo '<BR>';
echo $row['FinishesPrice'];
echo '<BR>';
echo '<BR>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I posted an update that explains a little better what i need. it wasn't about how to do a loop or a while in php to return data it's about what i do in that loop with each field the only problem is that i need to call a certain method for each field.